# Save PlayerPref on Button Press Unity 3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I'm currently developing a tycoon game where you can develop your own phones and then sell them.
It works like this:

Enter Phone Name in Input Field
(Name gets saved in PlayerPrefs for later use)
...
Press a button to start customizing
...
Customize the phone and phone cost variable gets saved in PlayerPrefs
...
Press button to sell the phone
...

Now the Problem I have with this system:
-Everytime I create a new phone it would overwrite the old phones Name and cost. I would like it if everytime you create a new phone it would automatically create two new PlayerPrefs, one for the cost and one for the Name and I could always recall them.

Something like This:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Phone1Cost)
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Phone2Cost")
PlayerPrefs.GetString("Phone1Name")
PlayerPrefs.GetString("Phone2Name")
```

I hope this was clear but basically I want to create two new PlayerPrefs on button click and they should depend on how many times you already pressed the button. So If you pressed it 2 times already(created two phones) then it should make a Phone3Cost PlayerPref, but if you already made 10 phones then it should make a Phone11Cost PlayerPref.

I Know this might seem complicated but I appreciate you help;)

Comment: This sounds to me like you don't want to use `PlayerPrefs` bu would rather opt for a proper database or alternative storing format like e.g. JSON or a CSV file etc

Answer (score 0):

See This will Work?

```
    private int PhoneCostValue = 40;
    private void OnBtnClick()
    {
        int howManyClick = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("howManyClick"); // for Get value
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("howManyClick", howManyClick + 1); // for save
        Debug.Log("howManyClick" + howManyClick);

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PhoneCost" + howManyClick, PhoneCostValue); // for save "PhoneCost" + howManyClick = this key will be "PhoneCost1"
        int Getcost = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PhoneCost" + howManyClick); // GetValue
    }
```

Comment: Ok, This will create so many PlayerPrefs so if you got error or something not work make sure you clear old PlayerPrefs.